# Copy Elision in visual 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, copy-elision

I was trying to test a small code to check if my compiler (under Visual Studio 2019) does copy elision, as it is no more optional for some cases under C++17.

So I tried the code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct myStruct
{
    myStruct() { cout << "default ctor" << endl; }
    myStruct(const myStruct& str) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl; }
    myStruct& operator=(myStruct other) { cout << "Copy assignement" << endl; return *this; }
    myStruct(myStruct&& str) noexcept { cout << "move ctor" << endl; }
    myStruct& operator=(myStruct&& other) { cout << "move assignement" << endl; return *this; }
    ~myStruct() { cout << "deleted" << endl; }
};

myStruct get()
{
    myStruct s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    vector<myStruct> vect;
    vect.reserve(10);
    cout << "Creating The Vector" << endl;
    vect.push_back(get());
    vect.push_back(get());
    cout << "Cretion End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So as far as I read, calling the function get() will trigger the RVO so I will get only ctor calls. But when I run the program I get (I added <<<<  in front of lines that are related to copy after calling get() function):

```
Creating The Vector
default ctor
move ctor
deleted
move ctor  <<<<
deleted    <<<<
default ctor
move ctor
deleted
move ctor  <<<<
deleted    <<<<
Cretion End
deleted
deleted
```

When tried with gcc I get :

```
Creating The Vector
default ctor
move ctor
deleted
default ctor
move ctor
deleted
Cretion End
deleted
deleted
```

So seems that Microsoft still didn't implement the Copy elision, or is there wrong in my code so I missed the real charm of Copy elision?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not really sure, but `vector::push_back` parameter is a const reference to `myStruct` and not a value, so you can't avoid that copy. I think you could get copy elision if you do something like `vect[0] = get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the copies in this case are required to be elided by any (currently existing) version of C++. The standard lays down several copies: the copy from `s` to the return value object of `get`, and the copy from the reference parameter to `push_back` into the `vector`'s internal object. The latter copy cannot be elided, and the former copy's elision is not guaranteed to happen at all.

If you're talking about C++17's guaranteed elision, this only applies to the use of a prvalue to initialize an object (of that type). That never happens here (outside of the temporary parameter passed to call `push_back`, but that's normal for any version of C++), so it doesn't apply.

Here's a simple test: if the source object of the hypothetical copy has a variable name, then elision if applicable is not mandatory.

Comment: may be I was not clear in my question, I was referring to the call of the function get().
normally the copy/move from the function to add into the vector have to trigger copy elision. Not talking about the fact that pushing to the vector call copy/move.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: "*normally the copy/move from the function to add into the vector have to trigger copy elision.*" No, it won't, as outlined in my question. The local variable `s` is copied into the return value of `get`; that's what `return s` means. This copy *may* be elided, but such elision is not required in any (currently existing) version of C++.

Comment: @ Blood-HaZaRd In the C++11 model, the prvalue foo{} creates a temporary which is used to move-construct x, but the move is likely elided by the compiler.
In the C++17 model, the prvalue foo{} initializes x. For more details I suggest you could refer to the blog:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/guaranteed-copy-elision-does-not-elide-copies/